# Do I have an instance of this object?

Tags: php, sql, variables, undefined

I keep getting an 'Undefined variable' notice when I call on an object I 'think' I have instantiated, but apparently haven't. I can't put a finger on my the error. The object is $fgmembersite, according to my error messages it doesn't exist, I'm confused about why. It maybe a simple case of me messing up my directories in the include/require portion of my scripts but I've been looking at them and can't see anything wrong. Tell me if you guys want to look at my file hierarchy.

And again thanks for the help!

I have three PHP files that are at play.

### First one is login-home.php

```
<?PHP
require_once("./profile_settings/view.php");

if(!$fgmembersite->CheckLogin())
{
    $fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("login.php");
    exit;
}
?>

/*a bunch of stuff*/
<img id="profile_avatar" src="profile_settings/<?php echo fetchAvatarLocation(); ?>"></img>
/*a bunch of stuff*/
```

### Next I have view.php which holds a function I use to generate the path-name of where I store my picture.

```
<?php 
include("./include/membersite_config.php");

    function fetchAvatarLocation()
    {
        $user_id = $fgmembersite->UserId();
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ddmembers WHERE id_user = '$user_id'");
        if(mysql_num_rows($query)==0) 
            die("User not found!");
        else
        {
            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
            $location = $row['imagelocation'];
            return $location;
        }
    }
    ?>
```

### And finally I have membersite_config.php

```
<?PHP
include("fg_membersite.php");

$fgmembersite = new FGMembersite();

//Provide your site name here
$fgmembersite->SetWebsiteName('Mysitename.com');

//Provide the email address where you want to get notifications
$fgmembersite->SetAdminEmail('My.Email@Provider.net');

//Provide your database login details here:
//hostname, user name, password, database name and table name
//note that the script will create the table (for example, fgusers in this case)
//by itself on submitting register.php for the first time
$fgmembersite->InitDB(/*hostname*/'localhost',
                      /*username*/'user',
                      /*password*/'password',
                      /*database name*/'database',
                      /*table name*/'table');

//For better security. Get a random string from this link: http://tinyurl.com/randstr
// and put it here
$fgmembersite->SetRandomKey('**************');

?>
```

### fg_membersite is a file that contains the class fgmembersite that stores a bunch of functions, the ones that I need it for are...

```
function UserId()
    {
        return isset($_SESSION['userid_of_user'])?$_SESSION['userid_of_user']:'';
    }

    function UserName()
    {
        return isset($_SESSION['username_of_user'])?$_SESSION['username_of_user']:'';
    }
```

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object is not in the scope of the function, so it is undefined. You need to pass it in as a parameter:

```
function fetchAvatarLocation( $fgmembersite)
```

Then call it with the object as a parameter:

```
<img id="profile_avatar" src="profile_settings/<?php echo fetchAvatarLocation( $fgmembersite); ?>"></img>
```

An alternative is to use global variables, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: @user126 - It would, but that introduces global dependencies, which you don't need.

Comment: I guess it depends on how portable vs under-the-hood you want your code to be.

Comment: Thanks, idk how I didn't see that... one more thing though. Slightly unrelated question but it claims $query is a boolean when I place it as a parameter into mysql_num_rows($query) and not a resource, in the manual it claims that 'mysql_query' returns a resource. And one more thing is it it okay to using the old mysql api for new development? It seems to claim otherwise on the PHP manual. Again thanks for helping!

Comment: No, you should use a different API for new development. See the comments to your question. Also, you're getting a boolean value because your query is failing some reason, which is another question in itself.